# How to Update only Assets folder without updating an application

Tags: java, android

I'm making an Routine app for my College for 5 Sections from Android studio and for easy access, I have designed and coded Routine in Html and placed inside the assets folder. 
As the Routine gets changed periodically within 4-5 weeks, Is there any way the contents of assets folder could be replaced with new files without need of updating whole application

Any Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way the contents of assets folder could be replaced with new files without need of updating whole application

No, sorry. Assets and resources are read-only at runtime. You are welcome to download new content and use it, but you would need to:

- Implement the download logic yourself
- Have your code set up to check for downloaded content and use it, falling back to assets if there is no downloaded content

Comment: I was thinking of hosting all html files in some webserver and then write any code to check whether a new file is availaible or not if it is return new update is availaible and update if now ..return your data is upto date but has no such vast coding skilss or don't know if it could really be applied or not.